# How to use LaTeX tables with MS Word/PowerPoint

Tags: tables, msword, powerpoint, latex-to-word

I love LaTeX's modularity and that I can generate (w/ Stata) and `\input{}` tables, which makes it really easy to update my work and to keep the same analyses across papers and presentations.

But not all of my collaborators use LaTeX. Is there a way to use my LaTeX tables in Word/PowerPoint? I see that I can [link to a file in PowerPoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/link-or-embed-files-HP005243121.aspx), but can I do the same with tables? That is, is there a way to have Word/PowerPoint compile my LaTeX tables?

Is my only option write the LaTeX table to a pdf, then screen capture, then link this file? This seems very manual and eliminates the "always up to date" feature. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Make presentations in beamer, that's more easy and pretty than powerpoint.

Comment: Unfortunately, Kurt is right. Even without issues of compilation, to include PDFs in MS Office as *high resolution pictures*, you need to either use snapshot or first save-as a high quality `.jpg` or `.png` and then insert into your office document.

Comment: Try http://texpoint.necula.org/manual.html. It processes Tex code within Word and Powerpoint. Using `\input{Your File Here}` and then ReTex Displays, it will also update as your tables change.

Comment: My vote is for Beamer. But there is also MyTexPoint thd.pnpi.spb.ru/~gromov/mytexpoint.html (needs MikTeX installed). It is designed for math but would be interesting to know if it can be hacked for tables as well. I don't see why not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To say it short: No.

Word has no inbuild `tex` distribution or engine to handle the LaTeX tables.

If you want to have LaTeX table in Word you can build it in LaTeX, compile it (with document class `minimal` or `standalone`) and add the resulting pdf in Word.

As far as I know is there no other way you want ...

**Edit**: Perhaps the best way is to show and teach your collaborators the beautiful typography of LaTeX ...

**Edit**: If you can include a pdf in your Word document directly depends on your used version of Word. Since Word 2010 you can do it directly (search msword include pdf file), before version 2010 not. Then you need the hints in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. So maybe the best solution in this case is to generate one exactly cropped pdf per table? I'll have to see if I can do that programmatically. In any case that may be easier than converting some people. :-) thanks.

Comment: @RichardHerron One cropped pdf per table is exactly that what I had in mind --- if converting some people does not work ;-) I converted some people with showing the the brilliant results of formula in LaTeX and (after you have learned it) the much more easier way to write formulas in LaTeX than in Word.

Comment: To create a cropped PDF per table, you might want to use the `standalone` package. It will output a PDF the size of the table you are creating. To convert the PDF to another format, you could use Imagemagick.

Comment: To convert the PDF to another format you can also use GIMP (http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

Comment: Thanks, all. Good points about the resolution/size problems with the pdf solution. I'm sure that leads to unpredictable results. I learned that if you save tables to .rtf (Stata can) or .xlsx, then  you end up with a good-enough solution. You can link to the file (link in question) and when you reopen the PowerPoint/Word file the links update, which is good-enough if you can't avoid PowerPoint/Word.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Iguana Tex an add-on to Power point.
After adding this, you can click a button to create 'new latex eqauaion' which opens an editor in which you type the equation or table in LaTeX format or copy it (from your latex source) and paste into this editor. Click generate the equation or table inside powerpoint. You can edit later if you want (If you or your collaborators want to edit it, you can do it but you must have some latex distribution in your system.)